# cannot find module at function_module 469:15

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning nodejs from Courseera and wanted to run a code from command prompt in windows 10.But this error **Cannot find module** always occurs.Iam completely at aloss what this means.
   I have tried all the methods given in the other stack overflow threads but couldn't solve the issue.
   node and npm are correctly installed with versions v6.9.2 and 3.10.9 respectively.

```
D:\shaury\node-http\public>node -v
v6.9.2

D:\shaury\node-http\public>npm -v
3.10.9
```

This is the problem which is occcuring:

```
D:\shaury\node-http\public>node serve
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\shaury\node-http\public\serve'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: Please post your code. Do you use require with an absolute path?

Comment: var http = require('http');

var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 3000;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  console.log(req.headers);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.end('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
  })
server.listen(port, hostname, function(){
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

Comment: Maybe you need to run node server.js ? you run node serve . Im think its mistypo

Comment: It  worked with  node serve.js.txt     The editor was adding an extension .txt  to the file by default. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your code.

```
var http = require('http');
var hostname = 'localhost'; 
var port = 3000; 

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    console.log(req.headers); 
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
    res.end('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>'); 
}); 

//here you should surround your string in 'quotation marks' but make sure to use `backticks`
server.listen(port, hostname, function(){ 
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`); 
});
```

Edit: actually you might need to check that you are in the correct directory. When you launch your app it should be from the directory that your .js file is or else supply the path.